# Customize serializer's field display

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a serialize :

```
class MovieShowtimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MovieShowtime
        fields = ( 'movietime', 'mvtype', )
```

And the resulti is:

```
        {
            "movietime": "2014-12-30T01:45:00Z", 
            "mvtype": "3D"
        }, 
        {
            "movietime": "2014-12-30T06:00:00Z", 
            "mvtype": "3D"
        }, 
        {
            "movietime": "2014-12-30T10:20:00Z", 
            "mvtype": "3D"
        }
```

I want to know Can it display directly like: 
Please help me thank you

```
        {
            "mvtype": "3D":{
                            "movietime": "2014-12-30T01:45:00Z", 
                            "movietime": "2014-12-30T06:00:00Z", 
                            "movietime": "2014-12-30T10:20:00Z", 
                            }

        }
```

models.py

```
class Showtime(models.Model):
    movietime       = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    mvtype          = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

UPDATE:  I edit my code below:

```
class MovieShowtimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    newshowtimes = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_newshowtimes')
    def get_newshowtimes(self, obj):
        movietimes={}
        getmovietype = obj.mvtype
        if obj.mvtype not in movietimes:
            movietimes[getmovietype] = []
        movietimes[getmovietype].append(obj.movietime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
        return movietimes
    class Meta:
        model = MovieShowtime
        fields = ( 'newshowtimes', )
```

result:

```
"results": [
    {
        "newshowtimes": {
            "\u6578\u4f4d": [
                "2014-12-29T02:20:00.000000Z"
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "newshowtimes": {
            "\u6578\u4f4d": [
                "2014-12-29T06:25:00.000000Z"
            ]
        }
    },
```

But the result is still not what I want 
How can I combine the two newshowtimes :

```
"results": [
    {
        "newshowtimes": {
            "\u6578\u4f4d": [
                "2014-12-29T02:20:00.000000Z"
                "2014-12-29T06:25:00.000000Z"
            ]
        }
    },
```

Please help me thank you!

Comment: `"mvtype": "3D":` isn't valid Python or JSON, do you need to have the `mvtype` key or would just the type (`3D`) work?

Comment: It's possible. Post your models. How `movietime` is related to `mvtype`?

Comment: they are fields in ````Showtime```` model